# How I capture an event from the given url React-Native WebView

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-webview

How add Event listener to React-Native WebView. ie, How I capture the event from the given url, my code is given below its not working..

```
     let  INJECTEDJAVASCRIPT="window.addEventListener('callBack', function(event) {console.log(event,'lops')});true;"

         <WebView
            key={this.state.key}
            ref={(ref) => { this.webview = ref; }}
            source={{uri:this.state.url || this.props.url}}
            javaScriptEnabled = {true}
            domStorageEnabled = {true}
            startInLoadingState={false}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            injectedJavaScript={INJECTEDJAVASCRIPT}
            style={styles.web}
           
          />
```

If you have any idea, please help me..
Thanks

Comment: what kind of event you want to listen to..?

Comment: a custom event from web

Comment: Please explain more about your question/

Comment: how I capture the event from the given webview url